# Is every point in the set defining some curve or line in $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ a boundary point?

Tags: general-topology

Might be a dumb question but is every point in the set defining some curve or line in $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ a boundary point? I reason that it should be since any point in the set has to be "next" to a point not in the set. If this is the case are there any sorts of lines/curves which might make this not true?

To clarify (sorry my question is unclear - I am asking primarily out of general interest/better understanding), if I draw a nice curve in say $\mathbb{C}$, lets say its simple and continuous, are all the points in the set defining that curve $C$ boundary points of $C$? If the answer is yes, does this apply to lines/curves that have arbitrarily many intersections and are otherwise not as well behaved? From the answers below it appears that are cases of lines which contain points which are not boundary points.

Thanks!

(Part of my motivation for asking this is in the context of the Jordan Curve Theorem)

Comment: A boundary point of what?

Comment: A boundary point of the set of points defining the curve sorry

Comment: Well what definition of curve are you using? It helps to know when giving a proof. Also do you mean $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$? The curves in $\mathbb{R}$ might not be very interesting, and probably it is not the case that every point of such a curve is a boundary point.

Comment: For now I'm thinking primarily of $\mathbb{C}$ and for example something simple like some sort of polynomial or rational function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily. Consider the [Peano curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_curve), a continuous surjective map $f : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]^2$ (the codomain can be identified with a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is you prefer). Not every element of $[0, 1]^2$ is a boundary point.

Comment: Interesting! Can a curve such as the Peano curve be a simple closed curve? The Jordan Curve Theorem says a simple closed curve divides a region into "exterior" and "interior" regions - with a curve like this though wouldn't you have some points not in either? Specifically the points in the curve that are not boundary points?

Comment: The first part of the question is about **simple** curves, i.e., curves with no self-intersections. The Peano curve is not simple (as the link you cite says, it is not injective).

Comment: @RobArthan: My answer addresses the question that was initially asked. The OP edited the question an hour ago and added the simple hypothesis; note that my answer was submitted well before that.

Comment: @AXidenT: The Schoenflies theorem says that there is a homeomorphism $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ taking your curve to the unit circle. This is a particularly easy setting in which to verify that all points on your curve are boundary points.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're interested in polynomial curves in the plane, I thought I'd write up the following.

Suppose your curve $C$ is the zero set in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{C}$ of a polynomial function $f$ in $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ (i.e. the set of points $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(x)=0$), then for any line $g(T)=(k_1T+r_1,k_2T+r_2)$, we have $f(g(t))\in \mathbb{R}[T]$, so it is either identically zero or has only finitely many zeros. I.e. for every line $L$, $C\cap L$ is finite. Note that the leading coefficient of $g(T)$ is a polynomial in $k_1$ and $k_2$ which is in fact the leading form of $f$ evaluated at $k_1$ and $k_2$, and is hence nonzero. Then if $k_1$ and $k_2$ make $g(T)$ zero then they are zeros of this form call it $F(X,Y)$. But then the projective point $[k_1:k_2]$ is a zero of the $F(X,Y)$. Since $F$ is a nonzero form, there are at most finitely many such projective points, so we can choose a point such that $g(T)\ne 0$. But this is just picking the direction of our line, so for every point, there is some direction such that the line through the point in that direction doesn't lie inside the curve.

Then if $x$ is a point in the plane such that $f(x)=0$, and $U$ any neighborhood of $x$, every line through $x$ intersects $U$ in an infinite set, since $U$ contains a ball of some positive radius around $x$. Then pick a line $L$ that doesn't lie inside $C$ Since $C\cap L$ is finite, while $L\cap U$ is not, there is some point of $U$ in $L$ not on $C$, which implies that every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point not on the curve for $x$ a point on a polynomial curve in the plane. Therefore $x$ is a boundary point of the curve.

Comment: Instead of "finitely many zeroes" it may also happen that $f(g(t))$ is *identically* zero. However, if $f$ is not identically zero, you can pick a point $x_0$ with $f(x_0)\ne 0$ and let $L$ be the line throuh $x_0$ and $x$

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen I believe I've fixed it.